# WPF MVVM PropertyChanged notifications in the ViewModel triggered by Model Events

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am having a problem understanding how to propagate a property changed event in a Model class up through the ViewModel and into the view.  I am trying to conform to the MVVM pattern so please keep that in mind.

I have a Model that I am trying to expose by the ViewModel.  My Model class queries an Api call to get the server status and exposes that status in public properties.  Ex:

```
public class ServerStatusRequest : ApiRequest
{
    //Exposable properties by request
    public ServerStatusHelperClass Status { get; set; }
```

Where `ServerStatusHelperClass` is just a wrapper for the combined results in the query:

```
public class ServerStatusHelperClass
{
    public bool ServerStatus { get; set; }
    public int OnlinePlayers { get; set; }
```

The cool thing about my ApiRequest base class is that it checks the cache time of a particular Api call and updates the Results by using a System.Timers.Timer.  So, for example, the ServerStatus Api call is cached for 3 minutes on the Api, so every 3 minutes my `ServerStatusApiRequest` object will have fresh data for it.  I expose a `UpdatedResults` event in all ApiRequest classes to notify when new data comes in.

Now I want my ViewModel to have an instance of `ServerStatusApiRequest` and bind to its `ServerStatusHelperClass Status` property and stay up to date with the changes every time the information is updated, but my view (for binding) can't know about my model, and thus, doesn't know about my `UpdatedResults` event in my `ApiRequest` class.  How can I reflect that out to the View through my ViewModel?  Am I doing something completely weird here?

Here is what I have that is semi-working but I feel is a very *hacky* solution:

In my ViewModel:

```
    public const string EveServerStatusPropertyName = "EveServerStatus";
    private ServerStatusRequest _eveServerStatus = new ServerStatusRequest();
    public ServerStatusRequest EveServerStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _eveServerStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            //if (_eveServerStatus == value)
            //{
            //    return;
            //}

            //RaisePropertyChanging(EveServerStatusPropertyName);
            _eveServerStatus = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(EveServerStatusPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateEveServerStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EveServerStatus = (ServerStatusRequest)sender;
    }
```

And in the ViewModels constructor I subscribe to the Model's event:

```
EveServerStatus.UpdatedResults += new UpdatedResultsEventHandler(UpdateEveServerStatus);
```

As you can see, this seems extremely redundant.  And I also ran into a problem where I had to comment out the check in the setter for `EveServerStatus` because at that point the `_eveServerStatus` was already updated to `value` just without it knowing and I wanted to fire the event anyway.

I fell like I'm missing a key concept here to link this all together much more easily.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Unfortunately that is how you do it.

Comment: @RyanByrne Please see my provided answer, I would be interested in your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a much better way to implement the behavior I was looking for.  Here is the code in my ViewModel:

```
    private ServerStatusRequest _eveServerStatus = new ServerStatusRequest();

    public ServerStatusRequest EveServerStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _eveServerStatus;
        }
    }
```

No setter as my ViewModel nor my View should be changing this data.  And Inside my `ServerStatusRequest` class I have a property exposing the `ServerStatusHelperClass` object as shown in the Question.  I have changed the `ServerStatusHelperClass` and made it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as so:

```
public class ServerStatusHelperClass : ObservableObject
{
    private bool _serverStatus;
    public bool ServerStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _serverStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _serverStatus = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ServerStatus");
        }
    }
...
```

`ObservableObject` is just a simple class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for me from mvvmlight.

By doing this my View is automatically updated when my `ApiRequest` class modifies it's `ServerStatusHelperClass` object.

Input on this solution is welcome.